# opening file error with duplicates

Tags: python, duplicates

I have this code:

```js
chain = '>'
contain=''

file = raw_input('Enter your filename : ')


fileName = open(file,'r')
for line in fileName:
 if chain in line :
  pass
   
 if not(chain in line):
  contain+=line
  print contain
  

fileName.close()
```

and this file.txt :

```
Python supports multiple programming paradigms, including object-oriented, imperative and functional programming. 
It features a dynamic type system and automatic memory management.
He has a large and comprehensive standard library
```

I got this result for the "print":

```
Python supports multiple programming paradigms, including object-oriented, imperative and functional programming. 

Python supports multiple programming paradigms, including object-oriented, imperative and functional programming. 
It features a dynamic type system and automatic memory management.

Python supports multiple programming paradigms, including object-oriented, imperative and functional programming. 
It features a dynamic type system and automatic memory management.
He has a large and comprehensive standard library
```

Why I have duplicates?

Comment: chain can only be in the line or not, your two ifs are redundant

Comment: yeah. I will as more conditions later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each iteration of your loop, when:

```
if not(chain in line):
    contain+=line
    print(contain)
```

since you concatenate each line in `contain`, when you print it, it will show you the first sentece, from the first iteration, then the first+second sentences in the second iteration, and so on. Hence the duplication.

Replacing `print(contain)` with `print(line)` will print the lines without duplication.

Answer (score 0):

After the first iteration, you add the first line of your file to `contain` and then print it.

After the second iteration, you add the second line of your file to `contain`, which still contains the first line, and then print it.

Same happens for the third iteration.

You are seeing duplicates because you are printing `contain` multiple times, and it has the previous lines in it.